# If I create an ACL using sys as sysdba for APEX_210200 does the ACL apply to sys

Tags: oracle, acl

Following this guide

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/azure-ad-authentication-for-oracle-apex-applications#add-web-credentials

So running this

```
  l_username varchar2(30) := 'APEX_210200';
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.append_host_ace(
    host => 'login.microsoftonline.com',
    lower_port => 443,
    ace  =>  xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect'),
                        principal_name => l_username,
                        principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
```

And then I try to test it with

```
l_json    CLOB;
BEGIN
apex_web_service.g_request_headers( 1 ).name  := 'User-Agent';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers( 1 ).value := 'Application Express';
l_json := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
  p_url => 'login.microsoftonline.com',
  p_http_method => 'GET'
);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_clob=' || l_json);
END;
```

But I get

```
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1182
ORA-06512: at "APEX_210200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 782
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

But the web credentials + Authentication Schemes does work from within the APEX APP itself (logging into Azure and returning to the app)

Does my test fail because I'm running as sys?

Comment: Did you try to add SYS as a principal?

Comment: I'll ask, I was programming via email on this one :)